# Unique constraint on one column with excluding row with same values in other

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to add a unique key to column `value` but I must ignore rows that have the same values in columns `value` and `header_id`. For example, consider this table:

```
id | header_id | value
 1 |         1 | a
 2 |         1 | a
 3 |         2 | a
```

So rows 1 and 2 point to same object and the unique key should accept them, but row 3 has a different `header_id` (pointing to another object) and, because it has the same `value` as object 1, it should violate unique constraint and raise an error.

**Edit 16.2:1327:**
I'm using a core framework that generates columns to handle history so I cannot normalize the table. My class has lots of columns but for this example I'm only considering the `value` column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a while I found something. Using constrain CHECK with function to determine if exist (Cannot use SELECT in CHECK statement but you can use function with desired select)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_value_free(_header_id integer, _value varchar) RETURNS BOOLEAN AS 
$$
  BEGIN
    RETURN NOT EXISTS (SELECT header_id,value FROM myschema.mytalbe WHERE value LIKE _value AND header_id != _header_id LIMIT 1);
  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

ALTER TABLE mytable ADD CONSTRAINT uniq_value CHECK (is_value_free(header_id,value))
```

Comment: That's a reasonable approach. You could also use `select exists(select 1 from table where ...))` instead of a `limit`, that idiom is usually recognized by the optimizer.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it if you can change your table structure slightly:

```
your_table
id   header_value
1    1
2    1
3    2

header_value
id   header_id value
1    1         a
2    2         a
```

Add a foreign key constraint from `your_table.header_value` to `header_value.id`.

Now you can add a unique constraint on `header_value.value`.

Comment: +1 Normalization. And you probably do not need the `header_value.id` at all.

Comment: I cannot change my table, columns id a header_id and others is generated by core framework to handle a history of object. My class have only column value (I mean class in Java). But thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use a trigger to simulate a unique constraint with your desired properties. Something like this would do the trick:

```
create or replace function sort_of_unique() returns trigger as $$
declare
    got_one boolean;
begin
    select exists(
        select 1
        from your_table
        where header_id != new.header_id
          and value      = new.value
    ) into got_one;
    if got_one then
        raise exception 'Uniqueness violation in your_table';
    end if;
    return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger sort_of_unique_trigger
before insert or update on your_table
for each row execute procedure sort_of_unique();
```

Then you'd get things like this happening:

```
=> insert into your_table (id, header_id, value) values (1, 1, 'a');
=> insert into your_table (id, header_id, value) values (2, 1, 'a');
=> insert into your_table (id, header_id, value) values (3, 2, 'a');
ERROR:  Uniqueness violation in your_table
=> insert into your_table (id, header_id, value) values (3, 2, 'b');
=> update your_table set value = 'a' where id = 3;
ERROR:  Uniqueness violation in your_table
```

You can create [partial unique indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-partial.html#INDEXES-PARTIAL-EX3) by attaching a WHERE clause to the index. This allows you to apply your uniqueness constraint to slices of the table; however, I can't think of a way to get the WHERE clause to specify an "anti-slice" so I don't see a way to make this work with a partial index. I could be missing something obvious though.

Comment: +1 for the partial unique indexes... i didn't know those existed

Comment: Idea with a trigger is good one. I so tried partial unique indexes but don't know how to write it. It throw error when want to use select in where clausule, so think its only to check value in that inserting row.