# Determine schema name of actual query in function

Tags: postgresql

I want use this for construction unique_key. But I don't want to provide the schema name explicitly. Is there some way to figure it out?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_value_free(_header_id integer, _value varchar)
  RETURNS BOOLEAN AS
$$
BEGIN
   RETURN NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT header_id, value
      FROM myschema.mytable
      WHERE value LIKE _value AND header_id != _header_id
      LIMIT 1);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

ALTER TABLE mytable
  ADD CONSTRAINT uniq_value CHECK (is_value_free(header_id,value))
```

It must work if I do this:

```
set search_path = schema1;

CREATE FUNCTION AS ABOVE

set search_path = schema2;

INSERT INTO schema1.mytable(id, header_id, value)
VALUES (1,1,'a');  -- Should be ok

INSERT INTO schema1.mytable(id, header_id, value)
VALUES (1,2,'a');  -- Should violate error
```

Consider multiple schema's with same table structure.

Edt: 2012.05.16-1533
Consider this tables for example:
Header_table: id serial
Snapshot_table: id serial, header_id int (FK to header table), value varchar

```
id               id | header_id | value
 1                1 |         1 | a
 2                2 |         1 | a
 3                3 |         2 | b
                  4 |         3 | b
```

etc. Record with header_id 3 would violate unique_key

This refers to: [Unique constraint on one column with excluding row with same values in other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310949/unique-constraint-on-one-column-with-excluding-row-with-same-values-in-other)

Edt: 20120516-2356
Add some test script (Sorry for this, I don't know how to join file)

```
drop schema if exists s1 cascade;
drop schema if exists s2 cascade;
drop schema if exists tp cascade; 

create schema s1;
create schema s2;
create schema tp; -- Temporary schema to hold insert function

-- SCHEMA 1 --

set search_path = s1;

-- * * * header table * * * 

CREATE TABLE th1 (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL,
    constraint th1_pk_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

-- * * * snapshot table * * *

CREATE TABLE ts1 (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL,
    header_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    version INTEGER NOT NULL,
    value VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT ts1_pk_id PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT ts1_header_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (header_id) REFERENCES th1(id) MATCH SIMPLE ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_value_free(_header_id integer, _value varchar)
  RETURNS BOOLEAN AS
$$
DECLARE
   b boolean;
BEGIN
   RAISE INFO ' ---- CHECK UNIQUE FUNCTION ----';
   RAISE INFO 'Search_path: %', current_schema();
   RAISE INFO 'Function caled schema: %', 's1';
   SELECT NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM ts1
      WHERE value LIKE _value AND header_id != _header_id
      LIMIT 1) INTO b;
   RAISE INFO 'Result: %', b;
   RETURN b;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

ALTER TABLE ts1
  ADD CONSTRAINT uniq_value CHECK (is_value_free(header_id,value));

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION logSchema() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    RAISE INFO 'Call on schema: %', 's1';
    RETURN new;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER logSchemaTrigger
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON ts1
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE logSchema();


-- SCHEMA2 --

set search_path = s2;

-- * * * header table * * * 

CREATE TABLE th1 (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL,
    constraint th1_pk_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

-- * * * snapshot table * * *

CREATE TABLE ts1 (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL,
    header_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    version INTEGER NOT NULL,
    value VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT ts1_pk_id PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT ts1_header_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (header_id) REFERENCES th1(id) MATCH SIMPLE ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_value_free(_header_id integer, _value varchar)
  RETURNS BOOLEAN AS
$$
DECLARE
   b boolean;
BEGIN
   RAISE INFO ' ---- CHECK UNIQUE FUNCTION ----';
   RAISE INFO 'Search_path: %', current_schema();
   RAISE INFO 'Function caled schema: %', 's2';
   SELECT NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM ts1
      WHERE value LIKE _value AND header_id != _header_id
      LIMIT 1) INTO b;
   RAISE INFO 'Result: %', b;
   RETURN b;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

ALTER TABLE ts1
  ADD CONSTRAINT uniq_value CHECK (is_value_free(header_id,value));

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION logSchema() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    RAISE INFO 'Actual schema: %', 's2';
    RETURN new;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER logSchemaTrigger
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON ts1
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE logSchema();

-- INSERT PREPARE DATA --

-- insert function to handle error
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tp.insert_data_test(_schemaname name, _header_id integer, _version integer, _value varchar)
  RETURNS VOID AS
$$
DECLARE
   schemaname name;
   b boolean;
BEGIN
   RAISE INFO '==== NEW INSERT COMMAND ====';
   SELECT _schemaname into schemaname;
   IF schemaname IS NULL THEN
       SELECT current_schema() INTO schemaname;
   end if;

   RAISE INFO 'Search_path: %', schemaname;
   RAISE INFO 'Inserting data: %, %, %', _header_id, _version, _value;

   BEGIN
      EXECUTE 'SELECT NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM ' ||(select case when schemaname is null then 'null' else schemaname end)|| '.th1 WHERE id = ' || quote_literal(_header_id) || ' LIMIT 1)' INTO b;
      IF (SELECT b) THEN      
          EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || (select case when schemaname is null then 'null' else schemaname end) || '.th1 VALUES(' || quote_literal(_header_id) ||')';
      END IF;

      EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || (select case when schemaname is null then 'null' else schemaname end) || '.ts1(header_id, version, value) VALUES( ' || quote_literal(_header_id) || ',' || quote_literal(_version) ||','|| quote_literal(_value) ||')';
   EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
      RAISE INFO 'Insert error: % %', SQLERRM, SQLSTATE;
      RETURN;
   END;

   RAISE INFO 'Insert succesfull';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- Wiht no current schema --
set search_path = default;

SELECT tp.insert_data_test('s1',1,0,'a');
SELECT tp.insert_data_test('s2',1,0,'b');

/* IF you do this above with before set search_path its go fine, but if you do insert from newone query thats drop:
ERROR:  relation "ts1" does not exist
LINE 3:       FROM ts1
                   ^
QUERY:  SELECT NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM ts1
      WHERE value LIKE _value AND header_id != _header_id
      LIMIT 1)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "is_value_free" line 3 at RETURN

********** Chyba **********

ERROR: relation "ts1" does not exist
Stav SQL: 42P01
Kontext:PL/pgSQL function "is_value_free" line 3 at RETURN
*/

-- Insert data with corect schema --
set search_path = s1;
SELECT tp.insert_data_test(null,1,1,'a2');

set search_path = s2;
SELECT tp.insert_data_test(null,1,1,'b2');

-- Insert data with incorect schema --
set search_path = s2;
SELECT tp.insert_data_test('s1',1,2,'a3');

set search_path = s1;
SELECT tp.insert_data_test('s2',1,2,'b3');

-- TEST DATA (Should for all violate unique_key)--
-- Wiht no current schema --
set search_path = default;

SELECT tp.insert_data_test('s1',2,0,'a');
SELECT tp.insert_data_test('s2',2,0,'b');

-- Wiht corect current schema --
set search_path = s1;
SELECT tp.insert_data_test(null,3,0,'a');

set search_path = s2;
SELECT tp.insert_data_test(null,3,0,'b');

-- Wiht incorect current schema --
set search_path = s2;
SELECT tp.insert_data_test('s1',4,0,'a');

set search_path = s1;
SELECT tp.insert_data_test('s2',4,0,'b');

drop schema if exists s1 cascade;
drop schema if exists s2 cascade;
drop schema if exists tp cascade;
```

EDT: 2012.05.28:1937
I tray it and found this in database (I did not see before)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_value_free(_header_id integer, _value varchar)
   RETURNS BOOLEAN AS
   $BODY$
   BEGIN
      RETURN SELECT  NOT EXISTS 
            (
            SELECT  NULL
            FROM    mytable
            WHERE   value LIKE $2
                    AND header_id != $1
            );
   END;
   $BODY$
   LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
   COST 100;

   ALTER FUNCTION schema1.is_value_free(integer, character varying) SET search_path=schema1, public;
```

But I need to have same code when creating database function and getting definition from database back with postgre function (like backup ...)

Comment: Why do you use the `LIKE` operator? The way you use it, it's the same as `=` unless you include the meta characters `%` and `_`.

Comment: In my case, duplicate records are if exact match (not case sensitive). 'A1' != 'a1'

Answer (score 5):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_value_free(_header_id integer, _value varchar)
  RETURNS BOOLEAN AS
$$
        SELECT  NOT EXISTS 
                (
                SELECT  NULL
                FROM    mytable
                WHERE   value LIKE $2
                        AND header_id != $1
                );
$$ LANGUAGE sql
SET search_path FROM CURRENT;
```

For an `EXISTS` semi-join `LIMIT 1` is not needed and the `SELECT` items are irrelevant.

Note that your unique function is not commutative so the table contents will depend on the order the records are inserted.

**Update:**

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS s1 CASCADE;
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS s2 CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA s1;
CREATE SCHEMA s2;

SET search_path = s1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;

CREATE TABLE mytable (id bigserial primary key, header_id integer not null, value text);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_value_free(_header_id integer, _value varchar)
  RETURNS BOOLEAN AS
$$
        SELECT  NOT EXISTS 
                (
                SELECT  NULL
                FROM    mytable
                WHERE   value LIKE $2
                        AND header_id != $1
                );
$$ LANGUAGE sql
-- Below is the most important clause
SET search_path FROM CURRENT;

ALTER TABLE mytable
  ADD CONSTRAINT uniq_value CHECK (is_value_free(header_id,value));

SET search_path = s2;

DELETE
FROM    s1.mytable;

INSERT INTO s1.mytable(id, header_id, value)
VALUES (1,1,'a');  -- Should be ok

INSERT INTO s1.mytable(id, header_id, value)
VALUES (2,2,'a');  -- Should violate error
```

Comment: `FROM CURRENT` is a very nice feature, but I suspect it does *not* what the OP wants. It sets the `search_path` of the function to the current search_path. But the OP seems to want the function to use the schema the table resides in. The above example would fail - provided I understand the question after reading many times.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: I believe the OP wants to write scripts to create tables and constraints for different schemas, only altering the `search_path`. If created this way, the constraint on `s1.mytable` will use `s1.is_value_free` which in turn will always check `s1.mytable`, even if called with `search_path = s2`.

Comment: Upon re-reading I can see your interpretation. I was under the impression the OP tries to write *one* function and reuse it many times. As `FROM CURRENT` binds at creation time this would not work.

Comment: Yes thats what I mean. Function must not depend on currently set search_path, it must always use scheme, where function is created. respectively where table is created

Comment: @Perlos: if it's OK with you to create one function per schema, the provided solution would do exactly that.

Comment: @Perlos: The alternative would be to write a trigger. (That's what I would do in any case.) Or if you can use `value = _value` instead of `value LIKE _value`, a [UNIQUE multicolumn index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-multicolumn.html) would do the job.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: `UNIQUE` won't help here. If `(1, 1)` is already there, OP wants to allow another instances of `(1, 1)` but deny `(1, 2)`, `(1, 3)` etc. It's not commutative and hence not implementable with `UNIQUE` or `EXCLUDE`.

Comment: @Erwin Brandstetter: I want use multicomulmn index before but cannot get to work exactly what i want.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Problem is with select. If I dont set search_path function crash because doesn use their schema and dont know where search for table

Comment: @Perlos: please post the exact script (which creates table, function and the constraint) and the error message, so that it would be reproducible.

Comment: Took the liberty to simplify the function. No more time right now.

Comment: `PL/pgSQL` is an overkill here.

Comment: @Quassnoi: I cant give you exactly my scripts. I work on commercial product. But it relates to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310949/unique-constraint-on-one-column-with-excluding-row-with-same-values-in-other

Comment: @Perlos: make simplified reproducible scripts then. It works on my machine.

Comment: @Quassnoi: I did test for you, so test it if is ok.  Sorry to log output, didn't know how to suppress execute query name

Comment: @Perlos: the most important part of my answer was `SET search_path FROM current` which is not present in your scripts. See the post update for the complete script which works.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Hi, I test your script and it seems to be working exactly what I want. I don't tested before because ErwinBrandstetter write thats it set search_path and i tested before and know the search_path is a bad way. How is work this code?? SET search_path FROM current - I really hope thats set search_path only for function and not global

Comment: @Perlos: it works exactly as documented: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createfunction.html: *The `SET` clause causes the specified configuration parameter to be set to the specified value when the function is entered, and then restored to its prior value when the function exits*

Comment: @Quassnoi: After a while I noticed that the database returns different create script than the one that I am used to its creation.  Is there some way, how to create function and exactly that get back??

Comment: @Perlos: please post it as another question